# Leer informacion de archivo csv

Tags: c#, csv

Estoy leyendo u archivo csv desde c#:

```
Nombre: , Jose
Apellido P: , Perez
Apellido M , Flores
etc..


string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\archivo.csv");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] data = line.Split(',');
    info.NOMBRE= data[1];
    info.APP= data[1];
    info.APM= data[1];
}
```

Cuando hago un `debbug` si esta leyendo el archivo, en line me el resultado es asi:

```
Nombre: , Jose
```

cuando pasa por `info.NOMBRE` sale Jose, cuando avanza a `info.APP` sale `JOSE` etc, cuando regresa al foreach ya esta en `Apellido P: , Perez`....después sigue a los info y en los `3` sale `Perez` y asi sale tambien con el ultimo.

Lo que necesito es que en cada `info.NOMBRE`, `APP` Y `APM` salga la información que le corresponde, no se como lograrlo

Comment: una primer aclaracion, eso no es un csv, le pusiste la extension pero solo eso tiene, es solo un archivo con un formato que inventaste

Answer (score 1):

La estructura que defines no es la de un `csv` ya que este no define los datos en columnas, para que sea un archivo que respecte el formato deberia ser

```
Jose, Perez, Flores
Andres, Dominguez, Suarez
Miguel, Martinez, Roca
```

O sea casa linea es un registro de ratos

```
List<ClassNombre> list = new List<ClassNombre>();

string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\archivo.csv");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] data = line.Split(',');

    ClassNombre info = new ClassNombre();
    info.NOMBRE= data[0];
    info.APP= data[1];
    info.APM= data[2];

    list.Add(info);
}
```

en este caso invente el nombre de la class usando `ClassNombre` ya que no la pusiste de ejemplo, pero cada instancia debes ponerlo en una lista

Answer (score 0):

Pero le pusiste

```
info.NOMBRE= data[1];
info.APP= data[1];
info.APM= data[1];
```

y con eso, las tres propiedades toman el mismo valor, lo que está en la segunda posición del data.
Si quieres leer tres datos, de tres líneas distintas, no puedes usar foreach ya que recorre las líneas de a una.